# Circle CI running UI Test but emulator64 is not in lib64 or lib64/qt/lib

Tags: android, android-emulator, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

Here I am trying to run the circle ci to test the android app.

This is the configuring file .yml uploaded to the GitHub.

```
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:

    working_directory: ~/code

    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/android:api-25

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "WIFIAPLoggingSystem/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "WIFIAPLoggingSystem/app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Chmod permissions #if permission for Gradlew Dependencies fail, use this.
          command: sudo chmod +x ./WIFIAPLoggingSystem/gradlew
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          working_directory: ~/code/WIFIAPLoggingSystem
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "WIFIAPLoggingSystem/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "WIFIAPLoggingSystem/app/build.gradle" }}

      - run:
          name: Setup emulator
          command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a" && echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a"
      - run:
          name: Check Libaray
          command: ls ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64
      - run:
          name: Check Libaray
          command: ls ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib
      - run:
          name: Launch emulator
          command: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib && emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel on
          background: true
      - run:
          name: Run Unit Tests
          working_directory: ~/code/WIFIAPLoggingSystem
          command: ./gradlew test
      - run:
          name: Run Instrument Tests
          working_directory: ~/code/WIFIAPLoggingSystem
          command: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
      - store_artifacts: # for display in Artifacts: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/artifacts/
          path: WIFIAPLoggingSystem/app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_test_results: # for display in Test Summary: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/collect-test-data/
          path: WIFIAPLoggingSystem/app/build/test-results
      # See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/ for deploy examples
```

The result of ls ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
ls ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64
emulator-studio-view.jar  libGLES_CM_translator.so  libc++.so.1
gles_mesa         libGLES_V2_translator.so  libemugl_common.so
gles_swiftshader      libOpenglRender.so        libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
libEGL_translator.so      libandroid-studio.so      qt
libGLES12Translator.so    libc++.so         vulkan
```

The result of ls ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
ls ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib
libQt5CoreAndroidEmu.so.5          libX11-xcb.so.1.0
libQt5DBusAndroidEmu.so.5          libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
libQt5GuiAndroidEmu.so.5           libfontconfig.so.1
libQt5NetworkAndroidEmu.so.5           libfreetype.so.6
libQt5PrintSupportAndroidEmu.so.5      libsoftokn3.so
libQt5QmlAndroidEmu.so.5           libsqlite3.so
libQt5QuickAndroidEmu.so.5         libxcb-xkb.so.1
libQt5QuickWidgetsAndroidEmu.so.5      libxcb-xkb.so.1.0
libQt5SvgAndroidEmu.so.5           libxcb-xkb.so.1.0.0
libQt5WebChannelAndroidEmu.so.5        libxkbcommon-x11.so
libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.so.5     libxkbcommon-x11.so.0
libQt5WebEngineWidgetsAndroidEmu.so.5  libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0
libQt5WebSocketsAndroidEmu.so.5        libxkbcommon.so
libQt5WidgetsAndroidEmu.so.5           libxkbcommon.so.0
libQt5XcbQpaAndroidEmu.so.5        libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
libX11-xcb.so.1
```

Clearly emulator64 is not included in any of directories above.

Is there any method to solve this problem?

There is no problem with setting up part but here is the message return when launching emulator.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib && emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel on
/bin/bash: emulator64-arm: command not found

Exited with code exit status 127
```

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60434954/circleci-emulator64-arm-command-not-found