# CircleCi emulator64-arm: command not found

Tags: android, kotlin, circleci

I try to launch my instrumentation test in Circle Ci.
I have this following code :

```
test_ui:
<<: *build_environment
docker:
- image: circleci/android:api-27
steps:
  - checkout
  - *sdk_license_agreements
  - run:
      name: Setup emulator
      command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a" && echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - run:
      name: Launch emulator
      command: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib && emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel on
      background: true
  - run:
      name: Run Ui Tests
      command: ./gradlew connectedciDebugAndroidTest
```

And I have this following error on my `Launch emulator` :

```
emulator64-arm: command not found
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Are there any surrounding logs?

Comment: No i didnt, sorry :(

Comment: I can help you with this if you can bootstrap some code and post it on GitHub.